# Discord JS Can't Clear all reactions

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make a polling function for my Discord JS bot using collectors. I followed the guide on making collectors [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#basic-reaction-collector). My exact code is as follows:

```js
client.on('message', msg => {

  msg.channel.send("This message has a reactor collector").then(function(mesg) {
    const filter = (reaction, user) => {
      return true
    }
    const collector = mesg.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });
    collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {

      }
    });
    collector.on('end', collected => {
      mesg.reactions.removeAll().catch(error => console.error('Failed to clear reactions: ', error));
    })
  }
}
```

The error is when I try to clear all the reactions in the `collector.on('end'` statement. Here is the exact error:
`TypeError: mesg.reactions.removeAll is not a function`
I used the exact same code for removing reactions as per [this](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#removing-all-reactions) link, but it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: What is your discord.js version?

Comment: Welcome!
Please add `discord.js` to the tags.

Comment: I believe that I'm using the latest version (12.3.1) of Discord JS.

Comment: The link doesn't seem to work anymore, the site won't load

Answer (score 1):

your code had some paranthesis missing. Here's the working reaction collector. You just need to change "true" with your wanted filter.

```
msg.channel.send("This message has a reactor collector")
.then((mesg) => {
    const collector = msg.createReactionCollector(true, { time: 5000 }); // replace this

    collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
        // 
    });

    collector.on('end', collected => {
        mesg.reactions.removeAll().catch(error => console.error('Failed to clear reactions: ', error));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code appear to have false/none placed brackets and you have an obvious problem with an not defind function.

First of all the false brackets are(in your code example): line 10, missing bracket ')'
and last line, should be an ')' to close the client.on event.

Another problem in this script is than 'collector'(line 12) is not defind because this variable is a local variable from the function above.

And the last and acually the only problem you where asking for is in line 12, to clear the reactions from the message the user sent just delete the 'e' in 'mesg' so u got the message witch triggered the event to run.

I hope this helped :)

Comment: For the future I suggest you to rewrite the code instead of commenting on each line of said snippet - you can do such with the help of [various formatting / markdown tools](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) StackOverflow provides.

Comment: thats what i tried at first but i couldnt post the awnser because of "not right code" or something simillar...